# "Persistent Shopping Cart" setting not available

Tags: ce-1.5.1.0

In Magento CE 1.5.1, the "Persistent Shopping Cart" item menu (under customers) isn't there. I have another install of Magento CE 1.5.1 on the same server that displays it normally. I've tried it under all different scopes, but it just doesn't show up.

**What should I try next?**

Comment: I think this is available only from CE 1.6 ? http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/persistent-shopping-cart-customer-segmentation-just-getting-better/ Are you sure the other install where it is displayed is also CE 1.5.1 ? Maybe there is a customization done in that shop?

Answer (score 10):

Magento did not release the Persistent Shopping Cart until Magento CE 1.6.0.0 so you shouldn't be able to see it in Magento CE 1.5.1.0. Attached is a screenshot of a clean install (with sample data) of Magento CE 1.5.1.0, it is not showing "Persistent Shopping Cart" under Customers.

[image: Admin Panel Screenshot Side Menu]
[image: Admin Panel Screenshot Top Menu]

[Magento CE 1.6.0.0 Release Notes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/release_notes#Release%20Notes%20-%20Magento%201.6.0.0%20%28Aug%2018,%202011%29)

If you can see it in another Magento CE 1.5.1.0, I am wondering if it is actually a CE 1.6.0.0 site, or a custom extension is doing it.

I would recommend first diffing both sites with a clean CE 1.5.1.0, and checking to see if core code has been changed, or if new core files has been added (like in the event of a failed upgrade to CE 1.6). Personally I use DiffMerge to do this, however there are several tools you can use.

Second, I would check what extensions are installed on each site and determine if any of them have to do with Persistent Cart.

Comment: No extensions. And it is the same version. Baffling...

Comment: @Gaia Never underestimate what sort of hackery the developers before you have done to a Magento system.

Comment: I installed this one and have been the only admin all along. Interestingly enough, see the screenshot of one of my 1.5 installs here: http://i.imgur.com/79sil1c.png, along with it's extensions: http://i.imgur.com/muLNgtd.png

Comment: I've seen core modules pulled down from later versions; and upgrades to later versions that didn't have `app/Mage.php` upgraded, thus the version discrepancy. I'd do a diff against a vanilla 1.5.1.0.

Comment: Diff your code next to see differences. Then screenshot your extensions from 'System' -> Configuration -> Advance